# Accessing API from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

I have a website which I have added as an extension in Google Chrome. What I need is that I have to access a server file from the extension. And I need is that whatever the server file outputs, I need to access the output in the extension.
Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Calpine Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Log on to calpinemate",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension",
        "default_icon": "calpine_not_logged_in.png"
    },

    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["http://calpinemate.com/"]
    }
}
```

Here is my background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ "url": "http://calpinemate.com" });
});
```

Now what I need is that I have a server file (index.php) which outputs 1. Now what I need is that I want to get this 1 in extension. That is whatever the file outputs I want that output in extension. How can I do that?
Here is my index.php

```
<?php echo 1 ;?>
```

I tried this.But still it is only working on Onclick event.Please check  my code.
Here is my background.js

```
   function getGmailUrl() {
   return "http://calpinemate.com/";
   }
   function isGmailUrl(url) {

      return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
      }
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(gotopage);

      function gotopage(){    
      chrome.tabs.query({
       url: "http://calpinemate.com/*",
      currentWindow: true
     }, function(tabs) {
    if (tabs.length > 0) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        console.log("Found (at least one) Gmail tab: " + tab.url);
        console.log("Focusing and refreshing count...");
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
         updateIcon();
    } else {
        console.log("Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...");
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: getGmailUrl() });
         updateIcon();
    }
      });
    }

        if (chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.onStartup) {
      chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {

       updateIcon();
      });
      } else {
        chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {

        updateIcon();
           });
         }
     function updateIcon(){

   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
         if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
        localStorage.item=req.responseText;
        //alert(localStorage.item);
        if(localStorage.item==1){
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_logged_in.png"});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""});   
        }
        else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_not_logged_in.png"});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""}); 
        }
        // We received the data
        //alert("Data: " + req.responseText);
      } else {
        // Handle the error
        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);
      }
    }
   });
       req.open("GET", "http://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php", true);
      req.send(null);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First request permission to access your server:

```
// In manifest.json
...
permissions: [
   ...
   "*://calpinemate.com/index.php"
],
```

Then use AJAX to access the data:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            // We received the data
            alert("Data: " + req.responseText);
        } else {
            // Handle the error
            alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);
        }
    }
});
req.open("GET", "https://calpinemate.com/index.php", true);
req.send(null);
```

Comment: hi..it is showing ERROR:status code 0..What will be the problem?? index .php is in a folder named test.So I tried req.open("GET", "https://calpinemate.com/test/index.php", true).But then also the same error.What could be the reason?please help me

Comment: It is showing ERROR:status code 404.Please help me. I am not able to figure it out

Comment: Please check my question,I have included my index.php

Comment: Hi Thank you such it worked fine..I am so thankful to you..I have one more doubt..these actions take place when i click on the extension icon.How could we force the actions to take place just when the extension is enabled?I mean without clicking on the extension icon,it should access index.php.How it is possible?please help me

Comment: When exactly do you want the action to take place ? What do you mean by _"when the extension is enabled"_ ?

Comment: I mean just when the extension is installed in the google chrome,these actions should take place.That means in chrome://extensions/,after uploading the extension,we enable the extension.At the time we enable the extension,automatically it should access the index.php.And also if we click on the icon also,this action should take place.How can I do it?Please help me

Comment: It is working just fine on the Onclick event.How can it work without clicking on the extension icon?

Comment: I see you posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186771/how-to-periodically-check-whether-a-tab-is-created-or-not-just-when-the-chrome) on how to achieve that. I'll take a look and answer there if I come up with a solution.