# How to periodically check whether a tab is created or not, just when the chrome extension is installed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have set my website as a chrome extension.Presently when I click on the extension icon,it navigates to website's login page.And it access a server file and set's the color of the icon according to the output of the server file.Now what I need is that,all these action is performed when the extension icon is clicked.I want these actions to be performed just when the extension is installed in chrome.It should be checked periodically whether there is output from the server file,just when the extension is installed.
Here is my background.js

```
function getGmailUrl() {
    return "http://calpinemate.com/";
}

function isGmailUrl(url) {
    return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(goToPage);

function goToPage() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        url: "http://calpinemate.com/*",
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        if (tabs.length > 0) {
            var tab = tabs[0];
            console.log("Found (at least one) Gmail tab: " + tab.url);
            console.log("Focusing and refreshing count...");
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
            updateIcon();
        } else {
            console.log("Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...");
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: getGmailUrl() });
            updateIcon();
        }
    });
}

function updateIcon() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                localStorage.item = req.responseText;

                if (localStorage.item == 1) {
                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                        path: "calpine_logged_in.png"
                    });
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
                        color: [190, 190, 190, 230]
                    });
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
                        text: ""
                    });   
                } else {
                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                        path: "calpine_not_logged_in.png"
                    });
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
                        color: [190, 190, 190, 230]
                    });
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
                        text:""
                    }); 
                }
            } else {
                // Handle the error
                alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);
            }
        }
    });
    req.open("GET", "http://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php", true);
    req.send(null);
}

if (chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.onStartup) {
    chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
        updateIcon();
    });
} else {
    chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
        updateIcon();
    });
}
```

Still all the actions are performed on the `onClicked` event. How can I make it perform on startup event ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform a periodic check, you can utilize the **[chrome.alarms API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html)** (which will also work with non-persistent background-pages - in contrast to `window.setInterval`).
E.g.:

**In `manifest.json`:**

```
"permissions": [
    "alarms",
    ...
```

**In `background.js`:**

```
...
var checkInterval = 5;
chrome.alarms.create("checkServer", {
    delayInMinutes: checkInterval,
    periodInMinutes: checkInterval
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name === "checkServer") {
        updateIcon();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi I have another doubt,that these actions are performed when I click on the extension icon.bUT i NEED THESE TO PERFORM AS soon as the extension is loaded in chrome.how can I do that?

Comment: 1. `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(goToPage);` ensures the actions are performed when you click the browser-action. 2. `chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function(...` ensures the actions are performed when Chrome start's up (or when the user changes). 3. `chrome.alarms.create(...)` together with `chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(...` ensure the actions are performed periodically (e.g. every 5 minutes). So, combining (1), (2) and (3) you are covered for all cases ! (If still in doubt, you can always test it for yourself.)

Comment: All the code you need is provided above. For (1) and (2) the code is already in your question. For (3) the code is in my answer.

Comment: but when you combine all how the code looks?Can you please provide it?

Comment: You just copy my code and paste it in your `background.js` (at the very end for example). And also include the "alarms" permission in your manifest's "permissions".

Comment: What I need is that now when I click on the extension icon only it navigates to my website's homepage and the icon becomes green.But what I need is that without clicking on the extension icon itself,if I have opened my website's home page,then the extension icon must automatically turn green.What I am trying to say that without clicking the extension icon itself it should access my index.php.That means without clicking on the extension icon all the actions shoud be performed.

Comment: Hi what I am expecting is just like a google mail checker extension.In google mail checker extension,when the extension is enabled itself,it will check whether the gmail tab is opened.If it is already opened without clicking the extension icon,it will count the unread messages and display along with the icon.If we click on the extension icon,it will redirect to the gmail page.same way i also need.please help me,if you have an idea

Comment: Since you posted another question regarding the `onInstalled` event, please accept this answer regarding the periodic check of the tabs.

Comment: @user1991: If you think an snswer is useful, consider upvoting it as well.